# GridView Spacing

Tags: android, gridview

Hello i have a gridview with multiple items. I tried to add space on the items on top and at the bottom but i cant make it. Also the items in the last row are not showing well.

FragmentLayout

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/Overlay"
        app:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<GridView
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:id="@+id/gridView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnWidth="100dp"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/widget"
    android:clickable="true"/>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Grid Item

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="105dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/active"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="hello"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

No top Spacing

[image]

No bottom Spacing. Row is full shoing

[image]

Comment: on your `Adapter` check for the first and last item. If one of them set padding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply, Add `padding` to the `Top` & `Bottom` of your `GridView` plus those attributes

```
<GridView
  ...
  android:clipToPadding="false"
  android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay" />
```

ref: [+AndroidDevelopers](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/LpAA7q4jw9M)

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/widget">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    app:popupTheme="@style/Overlay"
    app:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



<GridView
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
android:id="@+id/gridView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:columnWidth="100dp"
android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
android:gravity="center"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"
android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
android:focusable="true"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
android:layout_below="@+id/widget"
android:clickable="true"/>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
android:id="@+id/fab"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"/>
```